# Copy settings from one particle system to another

Tags: particles, properties, hair

I'm trying to copy specific settings (that are the same across all of my hair particle systems) on a character to all other systems... but I can only see how to do it manually and I'm thinking there has to be a way to simply apply the same settings to other systems. Ex: I want all of my hair particle sysyems to have Adaptive render enabled with 2 degrees and 3 pixels while also having B-Spline enabled at 5 steps. I have one setting that's the way I want it but the others need to be updated. Any ideas other than manually going through all of them? (I have 12 systems so it's very tedious)

Comment: What is the "one setting that's the way you want it" 12 particle systems?

Comment: There are actually several settings (and quite frankly, I change settings to figure them out). I just need a way to copy a setting from one particle system others simply and easily without having to manually go through all 12 of them individually.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do some python. 
Traverse all the objects and then traverse all the modifier of this object, if the modifer is a subsurf set the modifier correctly.

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    for m in ob.modifiers:
        if m.type == "SUBSURF":
            ob.cycles.use_adaptive_subdivision = True
            ob.cycles.dicing_rate = 3
            ....
```

And do the same for the particule system:

```
for ob in bpy.data.object:
    for psys in ob.particle_systems: 
        psys.use_hair_bspline = True
        psys.render_step = 5
        psys.adaptive_angle = 2
        psys.adaptive_pixel = 3
```

Comment: I'm not talking about adaptive subsurf. I'm in the hair settings trying to apply the same setting for all particle systems.